list.files based on number range
I have multiple quarterly published txt files I want to import to R. The files are named based on the year and quarter they were published:
"DEMO12Q1.txt", "DRUG12Q1.txt", "DEMO12Q2.txt", "DRUG12Q2.txt", "DEMO12Q3.txt", "DEMO12Q4.txt", "DEMO13Q1.txt", "DEMO13Q2.txt", "DRUG13Q2.txt", "DEMO13Q3.txt".
How can I only select DEMO files from 2012 Quarter 2 to 2013 Quarter 3? I got the DEMO part but not sure how to do the year and quarter part.
filenames <- list.files(pattern = "^DEMO.*.txt",recursive = T,full.names = F)


Is there a reason why you want to programmatically load the files instead of loading the files you need one after the other?

There are 80+ files! I just thought it's quicker and less repetitive

Try list.files(pattern="^DE.*12Q[2-4]|^DE.*13Q[1-3]")

@AndreWildberg It worked thank you! What about DEMO from 2015-2020 - ^DEMO.*[15-20].txt doesn't work

Something like list.files(pattern=paste0("^DE.*", 15:20, "Q.*\\.txt", collapse="|")). Untested though.

You can pull out the Year and Quarter integers using, e.g., substr (since the positions in the strings seems to be fixed) and then filter/subset:
yr = substr(filenames, 5, 6)
qtr = substr(filenames, 8, 8)

filenames[(yr == 12 & qtr >= 2) | (yr == 13 & qtr <= 3)]

